# selendroid automating mobile web tests

Tags: android, maven, selenium, selendroid

I am getting the following error while running the selenium tests through maven

INFO: executing command:

```
 C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4\aapt.exe remove C:\Users\CAMPK023\AppData\Local\Temp\android-driver5204.apk META-INF/ANDROIDD.RSA

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.getUserDirectory()Ljava/io/File;
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.androidDebugKeystore(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:284)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.signTestServer(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:228)
    at io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder.resignApp(SelendroidServerBuilder.java:134)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.initApplicationsUnderTest(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:156)
    at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneDriver.java:93)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.initializeSelendroidServer(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:91)
    at io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer.<init>(SelendroidStandaloneServer.java:65)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.lauchServer(SelendroidLauncher.java:67)
    at io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher.lauchSelendroid(SelendroidLauncher.java:90)
    at pages.AboutDirectDebitsPage.startSelendroidServer(AboutDirectDebitsPage.java:29)
    at stepdefinitions.DirectDebitStepDefs.I_am_in_the_business_rates_direct_debits_home_page(DirectDebitStepDefs.java:30)
    at ✽.Given I am in the business rates direct debits home page(BusinessRatesDirectDebitSetup.feature:8)
```

Any idea how can I solve

Thanks
praneeth

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion If you are automating app on android API level 17 or above use appium rather than selendroid.
http://appium.io/